# Flickering issue in external monitor when used with Acer Aspire One D260 netbook (Intel GMA 3150)

Tags: hardware-failure, acer-aspire-one, intel-gma

I recently purchased a Acer Netbook, Aspire One D260. It runs flawlessly. Yesterday I bought a Samsung 23" TFT with a native resolution of 1920x1080. According to the information found in the internet and my local computer dealer, the Intel chipset can handle the native resolution of the monitor.

However, this is only partly the case. I use the VGA cable to connect, the monitor instantly switches to the native resolution and now the problem: Occasionally, especially the first 2 hours after booting up, I have a flickering all over the screen, sometimes the entire screen is shaking and spinning around like crazy. I figured out that lowering the resolution avoids the flicker but this helps only for some time.

I can rule out that it's the monitor's problem since I found no issues with another notebook.

Right now, I have no problems with the Netbook, for about 30 minutes I didn't experience any issues... But I don't know for how long, it occurs without warning :-) 
I'm worried that if I would bring the Netbook back to the dealer and explain my problem, after testing it on an external screen in the local shop, everything works just fine... And I won't get helped with the problem because I can't prove it. (I'm currently in Thailand and over here, customer service is nothing like back home in Germany)

What can I do? Is this a driver related issue? (I installed the latest GPU driver) 
Is it because of the VGA cable? (But why does it work sometimes without any problems and with no issues on the other notebook) I monitored the GPU/CPU temperature, nothing changes really over time.. Can it simply be a faulty GPU and is a replacement justifiable?

I'm really stressed now because for the time I'm writing, the flickering didn't occur... but for sure, soon or later it will happen again..

I forgot to mention, the problem also happens if the Netbook runs on battery, unplugged. So the only hardware that is plugged is the TFT screen.

...........and here it comes again, flickering has just begun.

Answer (score 1):

A few things to try:

- Try a different (known good) VGA cable
- Try to set a higher refresh rate
- Try disabling the effects on your desktop